# how to combine parameters of a date function to get the last day of a particular year in an postgresql query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need a last day of a particular year as a date in an sql query:
`date(table1.year+"-12-31")` throws: `ERROR: column "-12-31" does not exist`
how is it possible to concatenate it an get the date?

Comment: Date operation syntax is notoriously RDBMS dependent; you have not tagged yours, nor provided any sample data or expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I identified your DB as MySql. In this case do

```sql
    select date(concat(table1.year,'-12-31'))
```

in the fiddle, this `select date(concat('1999','-12-31'))` fetches this `1999-12-31`

BTW in `postgres` this is also valid

Comment: the rdbms is posgres but it works

Comment: @J.J.Beam I was about to say that postgres is good too